# Can I add some comment while debugging my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way in Visual Studio to add some comment to my code while I am executing debugging?

If I try to do it Visual Studio tells me that **changes are not allowed**.

Searching on Google I found many people that ask about this feature but I can't find a real solution to insert some comment into my code (only bookmarks).

Is it impossible or is there a way to accomplish this operation?

I know that in Java (using Eclipse) I can do it and it is very comfortable

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the bookmark feature of visual studio?

Look under Edit->Bookmarks->Toggle Bookmark. On my machine that's a shortcut of holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and tapping <kbd>K</kbd> twice.

There are shortcuts for previous/next bookmark, disable all, etc, etc.

You can also see a list of all bookmarks in the Bookmark Window (under the View menu) which allows you to name your bookmarks...

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Edit and Continue was not a good fix.  I could add comments, but the breakpoints would then all be off.  This is a very nice solution,  and lets me build up a TODO list of bookmarks as I go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx) (E&C), you should be able to edit code while your program is in break mode, e.g. you've hit a break point. It should be enabled by default, but if for some reason it isn't, you can read how to enable E&C [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx). For 64-bit applications, support for E&C was added with .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: I have enable it but I still have the same problem :-(

Comment: What type of asp.net application u are working on?
Check the Line writtent as "Edit and Continue is supported for 64-bit projects that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1."

Comment: @AndreaNobili Even still there are a few areas where E&C doesn't work, lambda constructs at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add comments as a deugging aid, i.e. not 'real' code comments, you can use a datatip aka pinned watched window's comment. Hover your mouse over a variable until the watch window pops up, pin it (top button) then expand comments (bottom button) and type whatever you want. These pinned windows are retained in between debugging sessions, and so are your comments. Combine this with bookmarks for quick navigation (Ctrl-k-k, Ctrk-k-n). Shown in action [here](http://www.nullskull.com/faq/917/visual-studio-and-net-tip-12-pin-debugging-and-commenting.aspx), additional info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The downside of this is the pinned data disappears when you stop debugging.

Answer (score 0):

**Sure! you can both add comments to your codes and even modify your codes while debugging your application.**

But, remember: you should **Enable and Disable Edit and Continue**([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue)) as khellang said, and check you are in **break mode**(rather than debug mode).